# Spurious 'None' cells loaded at the beginning of columns by openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I've been working on a function in python, using the `openpyxl` library, that will load columns from a specified sheet in a workbook and do some data conditioning before returning the columns in lists or numpy arrays.

To load the columns, I'm loading the workbook, getting the target sheet, storing the columns, then simply iterating through each column and appending the cell contents to lists:

```
    #open the excel file
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname, read_only = True)
    print('\nWorkbook "%s" open...' % (fname))

    #get the target sheet
    sh = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet)
    print('Sheet "%s" aquired...' % (sheet))

    #store only the desired columns of the sheet
    sheetcols = sh.columns
    columns = [[] for i in range(L)]
    for i in range(L):
        columns[i] = sheetcols[cols[i] - 1]

    #read selected columns into a list of lists
    print('Parsing desired columns of data...')
    data = [[] for i in range(L)]
    #iterate over the columns
    for i in range(L):
        #iterate over a specific column
        print(len(columns[i]))
        for j in range(len(columns[i])):
            #store cell contents as a string (for now)
            data[i].append(columns[i][j].value)
```

Some columns will load with several `None` elements at the beginning of their respective list that do not correspond to the data in the excel file. For example, a column with two empty cells at the beginning (left empty because of header space or whatever) is expected to load with two `None` elements at the beginning of its list but it might load with five or six `None` elements instead of just two...

It's consistent every time I run the function. The same columns will have this problem every time, which makes me think there is hidden data of some kind in the excel sheet. I've tried clearing the contents of the cells that are supposed to be empty but no luck.

Does anybody more familiar with the `openpyxl` module or maybe just excel have thoughts about why these mysterious extra `None` elements get into the imported data?

Comment: Would `if cell == None: cell = ""` work?

Comment: Yeah I could deal with these extra `None`s however I want to, like getting rid of all of them. But when there are actual empty cells in a column I need to keep them. I can't pop out all the `None`s because there might be real empty cells at the beginning of the column or throughout the actual data and I want to be able to compare multiple columns. Elements across columns have to have the same indices.

Comment: Okay, so theres actual numbers being replaced with `None`s if I am reading correctly. Interesting. No invalid characters?

Comment: No no, non-empty cells are not being replaced by `None`s. There are extra `None`s imported at the beginning of the columns. For example, a column where the data starts on the third row, with 2 empty cells at the beginning, might come in with 5 or 6 `None`s instead of exactly 2.

Answer (score 1):

The code is incomplete but it's probably worth noting that the behaviour for worksheets with missing cells is necessarily somewhat unpredictable. For example, if a worksheet only has values in the cells from `D3:G8` what should its columns be? openpyxl will create cells on-demand for any given range and I suspect that is what you may be seeing.

`ws.rows` and `ws.columns` are provided by convenience but you are almost always better working with `ws.get_squared_range(…)` which should give you few surprises.

Comment: Hmm, but you have to supply `ws.get_squared_range()` with the "coordinates" of the range. If you don't know them this would look like: `ws.get_squared_range(ws.min_column, ws.min_row, ws.max_column, ws.max_row`, right? Wouldn't the calls to `min_column` and the like necessitate auto-detection of the range edges anyway? Why wouldn't `ws.columns` be able to run the same routines to find where the columns properly begin?

Comment: This is a good tip though. I changed the code to first identify the target range, then iterate through it with `ws.iter_rows(range_string = ...)`.

Comment: The difference between using `ws.get_squared_range(…)` and `ws.rows` or `ws.columns` is subtle. Columns or rows will always return either full rows or columns and may thus create empty cells at the start of those rows or columns, whereas `ws.get_squared_range(…)` will only return the cells within the range.